# ssh reverse tunnel works, but Davmail not working through it

Tags: ssh-tunneling, davmail

I am trying to make Davmail IMAP server, which is now inaccessible (due to geoblocking, but that is not necessarily relevant) accessible by anyone, through my VPS server (called server). I have explained the connections between different parties in graph below.

[image: connection diagram]

I am establishing the tunnel from Davmail (not accessible publicly) to SSH server (accessible publicly) by this command

`ssh -g -R \*:2143:localhost:1143 -N user@server`

It connects just fine and works, when I use it on the SSH server itself as localhost. I am using telnet for debugging, in future, there should be IMAP (or IMAPS)

```
# telnet localhost 2143
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4REV1 AUTH=LOGIN MOVE SPECIAL-USE] IMAP4rev1 DavMail 5.5.1-trunk server ready
. LOGIN user pass
. OK Authenticated
```

However, when I connect remotely to SSH server on the port, it connects, but (almost) no data goes through:

```
$ telnet server 2143
Trying 94.130.99.72...
Connected to server.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

and connection is stuck. However netcat works, when used in this setup and data is transmitted botw ways. SSH client indicates, there is a connection

```
debug3: receive packet: type 90
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 4 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen  port 2143, originator 195.113.180.82 port 16119
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 6 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: connect_next: host 192.168.10.161 ([192.168.10.161]:1143) in progress, fd=6
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [195.113.180.82]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug3: channel 2: waiting for connection
debug1: channel 2: connected to 192.168.10.161 port 1143
debug3: send packet: type 91
```

Davmail shows initial connection, but no data is actually received on other side (as far as I can tell)

```
2024-03-03 17:06:44,338 DEBUG [davmail.imap.ImapServer] davmail  - Connection from /192.168.10.161 on port 1143
2024-03-03 17:06:44,338 INFO  [davmail.imap.ImapServer] davmail.connection  - CONNECT - 192.168.10.161:59732 
2024-03-03 17:06:44,382 DEBUG [ImapConnection-59732] davmail.exchange.ExchangeSession  - Test configuration status: 302
2024-03-03 17:06:44,383 DEBUG [ImapConnection-59732] davmail  - > * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4REV1 AUTH=LOGIN MOVE SPECIAL-USE] IMAP4rev1 DavMail 5.5.1-trunk server ready
```

server has firewall disabled

```
# ufw status 
Status: inactive
```

and GatewayPorts is on

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
GatewayPorts yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

How can I debug this further?

Comment: Check for firewall PACKET settings on both client and server... maybe there's something that drops the packets based on content or size. Also check for any network issues that might be blocking data transmission.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub: I have cleared all my iptables rules (checking iptables -L) and the problem appears to be the same... not sure how to find out about this more